# If an SVG image is defined inside a <svg></svg> tag in html, how can I combine with the rel="icon"

Tags: html, svg, icons

How does one combine :

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
```

with

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```

The "link" tag allows one to specify `rel = "icon"`, but it expects a file name ('vite.svg' in the example), but if one uses a `<svg>` tag to define the image, then one does not have a file name for the image.

Comment: Please describe what you mean with "combine" by editing your question.

Comment: I cannot edit at the moment, but by combining I mean : the "link" tag allows one to specify ' rel = "icon" ', but it expects a file name ('vite.svg' in the example), but if one uses a '<svg>' tag to define the image, then one does not have a file name for the image,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<link>` element is meant to define the relationship of the page to another resource, not to a part of itself. So no, there is no direct way to just define an element in the page to act as icon.

That doesn't mean there is no way to cheat on this. The `href` attribute accepts data urls, and you can take up the `<svg id="icon" element>`, serialize it, and push that string into the link:

```
const svg = document.querySelector('#icon');
const serializer = new XMLSerializer();
const str = serializer.serializeToString(svg);
const dataurl = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(str);

document.querySelector('link[rel="icon"]')?.setAttribute('href', dataurl);
// don't forget about iOS
document.querySelector('link[rel="apple-touch-icon"]')?.setAttribute('href', dataurl);
```