# Can <link> favicon svg use root CSS variables?

Tags: css, svg, favicon

I've setup an SVG favicon which is functional.

```
<link id="favicon" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.svg">
```

However, the svg cannot seem to access any outside CSS.

```
<head>
  <style>#favicon { fill: red!important; }</style>
  <link id="favicon" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/favicon.svg" fill="red">
  ...
</head>
```

3 attempts I could think of

```
<svg fill='inherit'>
  <style>
    .fav-path-1 { fill: var(--favicon-color) } <-- nope
    .fav-path-1 { --favicon-color: blue; fill: var(--favicon-color) } <-- works
    .fav-path-1 { fill: inherit; } < -- nope
  </style>
  <path class="fav-path-1" ...
</svg>
```

Is controlling the svg styles from outside of it possible?

Comment: `type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.svg">` <-- SVG is not `image/x-icon`. SVG is `image/svg+xml`.

Comment: _"the svg cannot seem to access any outside CSS."_ - yes, that's by-design: an SVG file used as a favicon is not rendered in the context of the page: it's rendered to an on-screen bitmap in an entirely isolated context and reused in multiple places, such as in your bookmarks menu/list, history, OS-integrated tab previews/jumplists/MRU-lists, etc where in-page CSS certainly doesn't apply.

Comment: Ok so this is impossible and we would have to swap the file out to change its appearance?

Comment: To be fair, I believe you can use (horrible, horrible) hacks involving scripts like rendering an inline `<svg>` (which _does_ use in-page `<style>` rules) to an offscreen `<canvas>`, then exporting that to a `data:` URI which is then used for the favicon `href=""`... (I'm not a fan of `data:` URIs for too-many-reasons, but I imagine that the _superior_ technique of using `URL.createObjectURL()` wouldn't work for `<link>` resources (I might be wrong though)

Comment: @Dai no reason to go via canvas, it is possible to write the SVG markup directly into the data URI, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75522104/if-an-svg-image-is-defined-inside-a-svg-svg-tag-in-html-how-can-i-combine-w/75526719#75526719

Comment: @ccprog simply re-serialising the SVG wouldn’t make it inherit the CSS rules from the parent page HTML. That’s why I think you’d have to render it.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to hack into the code of the favicon, *if its code is defined in the main document*. This method won't work with image files for the same security reason you cannot access their CSSOM.

##### Data URI

Suppose you have a `<link>` element like this:

```
 <link id="favicon" rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="data:image/svg+xml;base64,...">
```

Read and decode the favicon code:

```
const iconlink = document.querySelector('link#favicon');
const icon = atob( iconlink.getAttribute('href').substring(26) );
const svgDocument = new DOMParser().parseFromString(icon, "image/svg+xml");
```

...write the custom variables to the root element...

```
const rootStyle = svgDocument.documentElement.style;
rootStyle.setProperty('--favicon-color', 'blue');
```

...and serialize the result back into the data URI:

```
const serialized = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgDocument);
const dataurl = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(serialized);
iconlink.setAttribute('href', dataurl);
```

##### Javascript variable

Or, you can simply start out with an empty link:

```
 <link id="favicon" rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="">
```

and hold the icon code in a variable:

```
var iconcolor = 'blue';
const serialized = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    style="--favicon-color:${iconcolor}">
    ...
</svg>`;

const dataurl = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(serialized);
iconlink.setAttribute('href', dataurl);
```

##### Element in the DOM

A third variant, where the icon is held as a live part of the main document DOM is described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75522104/if-an-svg-image-is-defined-inside-a-svg-svg-tag-in-html-how-can-i-combine-w/75526719#75526719).

Comment: This is a very valuable answer, thank you.